# Using Java multithreading, what is the most efficient to coordinate finding the best result?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

Let me be clear, the method I describe below is operational. I'm hoping to improve the throughput of the method. It works, and it works quite well. We're looking to scale throughput even more which is why I'm looking into this.

The task at hand is to improve the performance of a scoring algorithm which returns the best score for a collection of tasks. I have collection of tasks that I perform the scoring on using an `ExecutorService`. Each task checks to see if it now has the best score, and updates the best score in a synchronized fashion if it is the new best. To give some insight into the scale I'm working at, Each task takes a fraction of a millisecond to complete, but there are thousands of them, resulting in several hundred milliseconds to find the best one. I execute this scoring algorithm several hundred times a minute. The result is that 30 second out of 60 is spent running this scoring algorithm.

When my thread pool is 8 threads (with 24 virtual cores), the tasks take 0.3 ms each. When I have 20 threads (same machine, 24 virtual cores) the tasks take 0.6 ms each. I suspect that as I add more threads to my `ExecutorService` thread pool that my performance is getting worse because of this synchronization on the best score (more threads contending for the lock).

I have done quite a bit of searching, but can't seem to find satisfactory (actually, I can't seem to find any) alternatives. I'm thinking about collecting all scores and either storing in sorted order, or sorting after all tasks are completed--but I'm unsure if this will be any improvement.

Does anyone have any thoughts of another, more efficient way of collecting the best score?

Here's the current methodology:

```
final double[] bestScore = { Double.MAX_VALUE };
// for each item in the collection {
    tasks.add(Executors.callable(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            double score = //... do the scoring for the task
            if (score < bestScore[0]) {
                synchronized(bestScore) {
                    if (score < bestScore[0]) { // check again after we have the lock
                        bestScore[0] = score;
                        ...
                        // also save off other task identifiers in a similar fashion
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} // end of loop creating scoring tasks

List<Future<Object>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks /*...timeout params here*/);
... // handle cancelled tasks 

// now use the best scoring task that was saved off when it was found.
```

Comment: Are you spawning a thread for each score value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I thought the threading framework I'm using was pretty clear above, please clarify your question.

Comment: What type is `tasks`? What does `getExecutorService()` return? (I presume that it returns an `ExecutorService`, but different methods in `Executors` return different implementations of `ExecutorService`, so I am curious about what it is).

Comment: `List<Callable<Object>> tasks`...
and yes, getExecutorService() returns the `ExecutorService`...

Comment: I think most of the overhead here is probably synchronization. Do you need it? Do you really need the array? You could look into having a single volatile `double bestScore` variable that is updated directly. If you need all the scores, I would probably add each score as it is generated to a `PriorityQueue`, or maybe a `ConcurrentLinkedList` that is sorted afterwards.

Comment: Not enough time to really evaluate it, but I would look into Akka. Sounds like this problem is made for it.

Comment: I would also question the approach of a thread per score. If it only takes milliseconds, thread creation/exit overhead is a major component. I would batch them up in hundreds to a single thread.

Comment: With thread pools, it is important to spllit up work into independent tasks. You did that, but when you tried to let each task determine for itself if it has the best score, you create a dependency which kills scalability. I assume you have a 12core CPU. If you had two 6cores, it would be even worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll have to take for granted the fact that you want to compute each individual score as a separate task submitted to an `ExecutorService`. There must be other benefits, otherwise the overhead isn't worth it. Normally, you'd implement a `Callable` that returns the score (or an object with the score and other pertinent results) when executed. After successful invocation of all tasks, all results would be examined in the main thread to obtain the best.

Given your constraints, however, one optimization you could try is using a [`DoubleAccumulator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAccumulator.html), which was intended for cases like these, instead of your one-element array and synchronization. It would look something like this:

```
final DoubleAccumulator lowest = new DoubleAccumulator(Math::min, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
/* Loop, creating all the tasks... */
for ( ... ) {
  tasks.add(Executors.callable(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
      double score = 0; /* Compute a real score here. */
      lowest.accumulate(score);
    }
  }));
}
/* Invoke all the tasks, when successful... */
double lowestScore = lowest.get();
```

If you need to track information besides the score, you can do something similar with `AtomicReference`, creating a data object that carries the task identifier, score, and any other needed properties, and using one of [its accumulators.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#accumulateAndGet-V-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

If your tasks are initialized by some sort of recursive, divide-and-conquer approach, resulting in non-blocking, equally-sized tasks, the fork-join framework underlying a parallel `Stream` might be a good fit too.

Again, though, I would point out that if more threads decreased performance, measuring the use of even fewer threads seems prudent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've recently been looking at a `LongAdder` for a simple count keeper (which is effectively a `LongAccumulator` according to the docs), so this is interesting to use the same approach, but with a custom score object. I'll look into this a bit more.

Comment: Hmm. With a simple benchmark, between the current method and the accumulator, there isn't much difference at all. I wonder if the approach should be to find better approaches for the need of the `ExecutorService` and tasks scored individually.

Comment: @jadz As I commented on akhil_mittal's answer, and mention at the beginning of my own, returning the score from the callable and aggregating them in the caller is the best approach. This is only if you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that you have 10k scores and you need to find the best score between all of them.Take your 10k scores and divide them up by the number of threads, so lets say you want 10 threads then each thread will get 1000.

Now each thread can find the max out of its 1000 completely in parallel. When all 10 results are returned you will just need to find the max out of those 10 to get the overall max.

Comment: I am familiar with this approach, it is used elsewhere in my system. There are other benefits to our current approach that we don't want to lose, which is why we're not breaking up the tasks into chunks. I'm hoping to find an approach that works within the current threading framework. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I've updated my code in the question to included the timing out of the scoring tasks, which is one of the reasons I've was referencing in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I have few concerns. In you code you have only one element in `bestScore` then why do you need an array? Why have you set its value to max allowed value for double? In that case it will always be the best score, Nope?

Also it seems you need to make sure all your tasks execute because only then you will be able to know the best score among the tasks. I recommend to create a new `Callable` for each of these tasks that compute a score, something like:

```
public class ScoreComputer implements Callable<Double> {
    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        double score = 0;
        //Compute and return score here.
        return score;
    }
}
```

Then for each task submit a `ScoreComputer` which will return a `Future<Double>` which will have result once computation is over. Then you can find max value out of all the computed results and compare it with your existing best score.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        double bestScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        List<Future<Double>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        //For each item in collection create a task and set it to run.
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        futures.add(service.submit(new ScoreComputer()));

        List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Future<Double> future : futures) {
            scores.add(future.get());
        }

        Double bestScoreInTasks = Collections.min(scores);
        if(bestScore < bestScoreInTasks) {
            bestScore = bestScoreInTasks;
        }
        System.out.println(bestScore);
    }
```

I believe this will provide you some idea. Also your tasks are very short duration then IMO using a cached pool makes sense here. As per Java Doc:

> newCachedThreadPool() creates a thread pool that creates new threads
>   as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are
>   available. These pools will typically improve the performance of
>   programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks.

Comment: You cannot `final double bob = 1; bob = 2` which is why the `double[]` is `final`.

Comment: Also, any score that is less than Double.MAX_VALUE will be less than the initial bestScore...re-read that conditional above.

I don't think I want a new cached thread pool each time as this is called several hundred times a minute (updating the question above with this context).

Comment: IMO you have a lot of tasks which compute score and you want to find best score out of them. If this is what you want then you do not need the last if comparison in my code.

Also if you use` invokeAll` it is like `Thread.start` which can be a performance killer in case your task takes a lot of time. Using cached thread pool is still a better solution. Why don't you benchmark your results before reaching to any conclusion?

Comment: After reading through your answer, I think you've suggested what I hinted at what I might do above in the question. You submit each task individually to the service (I build a list, then invokeAll()). You then look at the results at the end and find the best one. I'm not sure this would be a performance improvement. Part of the problem is that I want the scored task, not just the score. I'll clarify the question again.

Comment: Thanks for your concern on our threading architecture, but I'm not sure that is where my concern is. I'll add more data to the question. When my thread pool is 8 thread (with 24 virtual cores), the tasks take 0.3 ms each. When I have 20 threads (same machine, 24 virtual cores) the tasks take 0.6 ms each. This is why I suspect the synchronized().

Comment: The basic approach, if you allow it, is the best. That is, implement `Callable` to return a meaningful result that can be computed in a single thread. Then, in the calling thread, iterate over all results and pick the best. If you refuse to do this, my suggestion of `AtomicReference` is the next best idea so far.

Comment: By the way, the one element array is to simulate a pointer to a double, is it not? That is, just a kludge to allow all worker threads to manipulate a single shared variable (and the source of your contention).

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much a kludge.
I'll have to benchmark it, but I think that storing, then sorting, all of the results may be expensive as well. Maybe not.

Comment: You don't have to sort the results, just find the min. That's O(n). As for storage, you are already storing a bunch of tasks and futures. This shouldn't be much more. Hard to guess about performance though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to chunk it like EricF suggested I suggest you implement your own executor that kind of chunks it for you. This still allows you to define each score calculation as it's own `Runnable` (or rather, I use a custom functional interface, but the idea is the same).

First, let's get the speed test out of the way:

ScoreCalculatorOriginal.java (this is essentially your code):

```
public class ScoreCalculatorOriginal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ArrayList<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        final double[] bestScore = { Double.MAX_VALUE };
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            tasks.add(Executors.callable(() -> {
                Random random = new Random();
                double score = Math.pow(Math.sin(random.nextDouble()), 2) * Math.pow(Math.cos(random.nextDouble()), 2);
                if (score < bestScore[0]) {
                    synchronized (bestScore) {
                        if (score < bestScore[0]) {
                            bestScore[0] = score;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        List<Future<Object>> futures = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
                .invokeAll(tasks);
        for(Future<Object> future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Calculation took %.3f ms%n", (end - start) / 1e6);
    }
}
```

8 threads (my core count):

> Calculation took 103.358 ms

4 threads:

> Calculation took 104.351 ms

1 thread:

> Calculation took 102.918 ms

It doesn't scale at all.

Here's my take on it:

ScoreCalculatorFast.java:

```
public class ScoreCalculatorFast {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScoreExecutor executor = new ScoreExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        List<ScoreExecutor.ScoreJob> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            jobs.add(() -> {
                Random random = new Random();
                return Math.pow(Math.sin(random.nextDouble()), 2) * Math.pow(Math.cos(random.nextDouble()), 2);
            });
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        executor.getBestScore(jobs);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Calculation took %.3f ms%n", (end - start) / 1e6);
    }
}
```

8 threads:

> Calculation took 19.624 ms

4 threads:

> Calculation took 24.275 ms

1 thread:

> Calculation took 41.357 ms

As you can see it's significantly faster and it scales with the number of threads. Though there are diminishing returns to adding on more threads since some of the work can't be distributed over more threads and there is a bit of synchronisation involved at the start and end of the calculations. With more advanced score calculations that take longer time you'll see higher gains from more threads.

Now here's the implementation for you:

ScoreExecutor.java:

```
public class ScoreExecutor {

    /**
     * A job that calculates a score
     */
    public static interface ScoreJob {

        /**
         * Calculate the score
         * @return the calculated score
         */
        double calculateScore();
    }

    // This is the threads that do all the work
    final ArrayList<ScoreThread> threads;

    ScoreExecutor(int numThreads) {
        // Create the threads
        threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            threads.add(new ScoreThread());
        }
        // Start them
        for(ScoreThread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute a collection of ScoreJobs and return the best score among them.
     * @param jobs The jobs to execute
     * @return The best score from the scores calculated by the jobs
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public double getBestScore(Collection<ScoreJob> jobs) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<ScoreJob> jobList = new ArrayList<>(jobs);
        // Start all threads
        int chunkSize = jobList.size() / threads.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.size() - 1; i++) {
            threads.get(i).startJobs(jobList.subList(i * chunkSize, (i+1) * chunkSize));
        }
        // Start the last thread
        int lastIndex = threads.size() - 1;
        threads.get(lastIndex).startJobs(jobList.subList(lastIndex * chunkSize, jobList.size()));

        // Get the best score from each thread
        LinkedList<Double> threadScores = new LinkedList<>();
        for(ScoreThread thread : threads) {
            threadScores.add(thread.getBestScore());
        }
        // Calculate the best score
        double bestScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Double score : threadScores) {
            if(score < bestScore) {
                bestScore = score;
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }

    /**
     * Worker thread
     */
    private class ScoreThread extends Thread {

        // If we're currently running a score calculation
        private volatile boolean run;

        // The current best score
        private volatile double bestScore;

        // Latch for synchronisation with the executor
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        // The list of jobs to execute
        private final LinkedList<ScoreJob> scoreJobs = new LinkedList<>();

        private void startJobs(Collection<ScoreJob> jobs) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if(!run) {
                    // Start the thread
                    scoreJobs.addAll(jobs);
                    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                    run = true;
                    this.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("This thread is already running jobs");
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the best score at the end of the calculation.
         * Waits until all jobs are finished and then returns
         * this thread's best score.
         * @return This threads best score
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
        private double getBestScore() throws InterruptedException {
            // Wait for completion and return
            latch.await();
            return bestScore;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            run = false;
            try {
                // External loop, run forever so we can run multiple jobs
                while (true) {
                    // Wait for a job to be started
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (!run) {
                            wait();
                        }
                    }
                    // This threads best score
                    double bestScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    ScoreJob job; // The current job
                    // Get a job
                    while((job = scoreJobs.poll()) != null) {
                        // Calculate the score
                        double score = job.calculateScore();
                        // Update the best score
                        if(score < bestScore) {
                            bestScore = score;
                        }
                    }
                    // We're done, update the best score and release the latch
                    this.bestScore = bestScore;
                    latch.countDown();
                    // Set run to false so we wait for the next batch of jobs
                    run = false;
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main optimisation here is that each thread keeps track of it's local best score instead of updating the globally best score. We then let the executor pick the best score from all the threads' best scores once all the threads have finished.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! As you suggested, this is a much more detailed answer of the style that EricF suggested. I think with the specific approach you've shown, that I can still get the benefits of the way we've implemented threading, but introduce the optimization of each thread keeping a local best score.

I'm curious if you know why the original approach doesn't scale with the number of threads. Is it the synchronization contention between the threads?

Comment: If I build on your benchmark and simulate a task that is more realistic for me (run that loading calculation 2200 times, rather than just once to get a duration of around 0.3 msec per task), I don't get the same results that you do, nor the same results that I see in my actual code.

Comment: I should clarify...by "I don't get the same results" I mean that I am seeing acceptable scaling with adding more threads.

Comment: Yes. It's the synchronisation that causes your original code to not scale. Remember that a `synchronized` block will only allow one thread to execute that block at a time so what happens is that if you have 20 threads running. 19 of those threads will be waiting for the 1st thread to check if it's score is the new best before they can progress. With all the overhead of keeping a synchronised queue of jobs (which is something I avoided in my implementation) solutions like that only pay off if the code outside the synchronised block takes a significantly longer time to execute.